# SQLite FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi i'm tryng to make a simple database in my app but it crash when i start it. I think that the problem is linked to the addButton, deleteButton and PrintDb methods, but i can't fix it. This is the code of MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Definizione Variabili-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle; //Per collegare il Drawer alla toolbar
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private FloatingActionMenu actionMenu;
private FloatingActionButton actionButton;
private MenuItem mSearchAction;
private boolean isSearchOpened = false;
private EditText search;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
//Definizione variabili per Database
EditText maguiInput;
TextView maguiText;
MyDBHandler dbhandler;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//Definizione dei metodi della MainActivity-----------------------------------------------------
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, home);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    //PORZIONE DI CODICE PER GESTIONE DATABASE
    maguiInput =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.maguiEditText);
    maguiText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.maguiTextView);
    dbhandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    printDatabase();
    //---------------------------------------------------------

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Pemette di poter selezionare le voci del navigation drawer

            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.home:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, home);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.profilo:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ProfileFragment profilo = new ProfileFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, profilo);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.impostazioni:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    SettingsFragment impostazioni = new SettingsFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, impostazioni);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.info:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    InfoFragment info = new InfoFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, info);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.help:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    HelpFragment help = new HelpFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, help);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.logout:
                    actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    LogoutFragment logout = new LogoutFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, logout);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Somethings Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
  // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            //supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            onDSlide(slideOffset);
            toolbar.setAlpha(1-slideOffset/2);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    // Creo il bottone add che conterrà due sotto-bottoni
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp);

    actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(icon)
            .build();

    // Creo i sotto-bottoni edit e photo
    SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);

    ImageView itemIcon = new ImageView(this);
    itemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_edit_white_24dp);
    ImageView itemPhoto = new ImageView(this);
    itemIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_white_24dp);

    SubActionButton button1 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemIcon).build();
    SubActionButton button2 = itemBuilder.setContentView(itemPhoto).build();

    actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
            .addSubActionView(button1)
            .addSubActionView(button2)
            .attachTo(actionButton)
            .build();
}

//Metodi per la gestione del database
//add a product to the db
public void addButtonClicked(View v){
    Producto p = new Producto(maguiInput.getText().toString());
    dbhandler.addProducto(p);
    //printDatabase();
}
//delete a product to the db
public void deleteButtonClicked(View v){
    String inputText = maguiInput.getText().toString();
    dbhandler.deleteProducto(inputText);
    //printDatabase();
}
public void printDatabase() {
    String dbString =dbhandler.databaseToString();
    maguiText.setText(dbString);
    maguiInput.setText("");
}
//-----------------------------------------------

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    mSearchAction = menu.findItem(R.id.action_cerca);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //Attiva il click sul'icona di ricerca presente sull'actionBar
    if (id == R.id.action_cerca) {
       handleMenuSearch();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void toggleTranslateFAB (float slideOffset) {
    //Permette di far scomparire/apparire il FAB alla apertura/chiusura del Drawer
        if (actionMenu != null) {
            if (actionMenu.isOpen()) {
                actionMenu.close(true);
            }
            actionButton.setTranslationX(slideOffset * 200);
        }
}
public void onDSlide(float slideOffset){
    toggleTranslateFAB(slideOffset);
}

protected void handleMenuSearch(){
    //Gestione della ricerca testuale presente sulla actionBar
    ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar

    if(isSearchOpened){ //test if the search is open

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false); //disable a custom view inside the actionbar
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true); //show the title in the action bar

        //hides the keyboard
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(search.getWindowToken(), 0);

        //add the search icon in the action bar
        mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_white_24dp));

        isSearchOpened = false;
    } else { //open the search entry

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a
        // custom view in the action bar
        action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);//add the custom view
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title

        search = (EditText)action.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.editSearch); //the text editor

        //this is a listener to do a search when the user clicks on search button
        search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    doSearch();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        search.requestFocus();

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(search, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);


        //add the close icon
        mSearchAction.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_search_white_24dp));

        isSearchOpened = true;
    }
}

//Metodi per la gestione della ricerca
private void doSearch() {
    //Definire la tipologia di ricerca da effettuare
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isSearchOpened){
        handleMenuSearch();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------
```

This is class MyDBHandler

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

//We need to pass database information along to superclass
public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//Add a new row to the database
public void addProducto(Producto product){
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productName());
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

//Delete a product from the database
public void deleteProducto(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";");
}

public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";

    //Cursor points to a location in your results
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    //Position after the last row means the end of the results
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null) {
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
}
```

}

And this is the error

```
09-23 17:04:26.914  23457-23457/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android4dev.navigationview, PID: 23457
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android4dev.navigationview/com.android4dev.navigationview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.android4dev.navigationview.MainActivity.printDatabase(MainActivity.java:226)
            at com.android4dev.navigationview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using getReadableDatabase for reading values

```
 public String databaseToString(){
     String dbString = "";
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
      String query= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

  if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
                if(cursor.getColumnIndex("productname")!=null)
                {       
                 dbString +=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("productname"))+"\n";
                 }
       }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

Comment: nothing to do. it doesn'nt work. but thx :D